# Use F.countDistinct in a Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to use F.countDistinct() in a Spark SQL query using grouping sets which is only available through the Spark SQL Api but F.countDistinct() is only available in the Python/Scala API. I've tried to register it but to no avail.

Here's what I tried:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    [2020, "England"],
    [2019, "Wales"],
    [2018, "Ireland"],
    [2020, "England"],
    [2016, "England"],
    [2015, "Ireland"],
    [2006, "France"],
    [2005, "Wales"],
    [2004, "France"],
    [2000, "England"],
    [2002, "France"],
    [2000, "England"],
    [2020, "England"],
    ],
    ["year", "nation"]
)

spark.sqlContext.udf.register("countDistinct", F.countDistinct)

df.selectExpr("countDistinct(nation) as c_distinct")
```

**Then I got a very long error message with :** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't register Spark SQL functions as a UDF - that makes no sense. You just need the correct syntax. In this case, it would be

```
df.selectExpr('count (distinct nation) as c_distinct').show()
+----------+
|c_distinct|
+----------+
|         4|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I see so we just do it the sql way. It's confusing as the sql api also offers an approx_count_distinct function which is used like the syntax in my question, i guess they wanted to preserve the syntax.

i just guessed the countDistinct function hadn't been ported over as it's nowhere in the sql api docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#approx_count_distinct

Comment: I suppose the syntax is different in order to be consistent with the syntax of other SQL implementations (MySQL/SQL server etc)

Comment: Yeah I totally get that now I guess it just means that I can't rely solely on the spark SQL docs

Comment: There is another higher-level docs here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html

Comment: Count distinct is documented here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#aggregate-functions

Comment: Ah yes, I forget about that one as I mostly use the other so I can ctrl-f my way to what I want pretty quickly.

So F.countDistinct('test' ) creates the following col expression, Column<b'count(DISTINCT test)'> I should've just checked that in the first place!